# Equation for a geometrical half surface from folding a flat curved in one direction surface in half

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces, functional-equations

I cannot not formulate the problem as i do not know how to model this idea. This is an open question not an mathematical exercise so if anybody has a good proposition i'm happy to use it.

Sorry in advance for my not correct mathematical language. 
My problem is to find a surface which match the criteria that you can imagine as a piece of paper or non stretchable surface.  The schema is on the picture[folding in half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvlF4.jpg)

Imagine a strip of a flat surface not longer than $R$ and not wider than $2 R$ in the rectangular fashion. It is bend around the Radius $R$ so it is actually part of a cylinder. Now if you like to fold in in half along a arc witch cuts this rectangle in half, so along a edge with is bend with the radius R, what surface does it has to follow to move smoothly from one side to another.

I understand that actually a stiff surface cannot be bend this way but is there a approximation witch would allow to bend a piece of paper like this over in a smooth way? 
[approximate way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoKBG.jpg)
I solved this numerically by the assumption that a curve has to be always on a distance r from the arc. each curve is following a tourous created around the circle $R$ with the radius $r$. but this is a very unsatisfying model.

I started my self on the equations but they came out not solvable to me.
I am a Student of mechatronics a need to tackle this problem down.

Comment: Did you try it with actual paper? I believe what you want is not in fact physically realizable

Comment: you are right. it is not. the paper surface can be imagined as a 2d raster which cannot be screwed. all angels have to be 90 degrees all the time. but actually with a fine movement and slight of hand by using the bit flexibility in the paper it is possible to flip it without hurting it. so there has to be a proximate surface based on that idea which complies to most of the rules

Answer (score 0):

Work in [cylindrical co-ordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html) $(r,\theta,z)$. Let the big strip of flat surface be given by $r=R$, $0\leq \theta\leq 1$ and $-R\leq z \leq R$. This has length $R$ in the "curved" direction (going around the cylinder) and width 2R in the "straight" direction (parallel to the axis of the cylinder).

As I understand your question, you have two line segments and you want a  simple-looking smooth surface which connects them. One line segment is $r=R$, $\theta=0$, $-R\leq z\leq 0$. The second line segment is $r=R$, $\theta = 1$, $0\leq z \leq R$.

An example of such a surface is given in parametric form by $$(r,\theta,z)=(R+t\sin(\pi\theta),\theta,R+t\cos(\pi\theta))$$ where $0\leq \theta\leq 1$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$.